# Funcion para convertir grados celsius a fahrenheit en Javascript y html

Tags: javascript, html, funciones

Quiero crear una funcion en la que reciba como parametro un valor de temperatura en celsius y lo que convierta ese valor a fahrenheit.
Estoy teniendo problemas para mostrar el mensaje en un parrafo del valor de la conversion realizada.

Mi codigo HTML consiste en un input de tipo numerico y un boton que al ser presionado muestre la conversion realizada. Cuando aprieto el boton no se muestra ningun mensaje.
Este es el codigo:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", inicio);

function inicio (){
    document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", mostrarEjercicio);
}

function convertirCelsiusAFahrenheit(temperatura) {
    let conversion = (temperatura * 1.8) + 32;

    return conversion;

}

function mostrarEjercicio(){
    let laTemperatura = Number(document.querySelector("#val1").value);

    let temperaturaEnFahrenheit = convertirCelsiusAFahrenheit(laTemperatura);
    
    if (temperaturaEnFahrenheit) {
        mensaje = "la temperatura en fahrenheit es "+conversion;
        
    }

    document.querySelector("#resultado").innerHTML = mensaje;


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="Ejercicio.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <label for="val1">Ingrese temperatura:</label>
        <input type="number" id="val1"><br>
        <input type="button" value="Convertir" id="btn">
    </form>
    <p id="resultado"></p>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Agradezco cualquier ayuda y mejoras.

Comment: Por favor, indica con más claridad qué problemas tienes. Pon en tu pregunta los mensajes de error o los resultados incorrectos.Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!

Comment: Creo que ahora deberia entenderse mejor mi problema. Gracias por el comentario

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: conversion is not defined` -> ese es tu error. **Solución** -> declara conversión fuera de las funciones para que sea global. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/es5nb3ju/1/)

Comment: let temperaturaEnFahrenheit = convertirCelsiusAFahrenheit(laTemperatura); esta guarda el resultado,  mensaje = "la temperatura en fahrenheit es "+conversion; cambia esto por la variable temperaturaEnFahrenheit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En la función `mostrarEjercicio` estas tratando de asignar una variable que no existe (`conversion`). El valor que te devuelve la función lo asignas a `temperaturaEnFahrenheit`, esa es la variable que debes usar. La variable `mensaje` también debes declararla, ya sea con `const`, `let` o `var`:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", inicio);

function inicio (){
document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", mostrarEjercicio);
}

function convertirCelsiusAFahrenheit(temperatura) {
return (temperatura * 1.8) + 32;
}

function mostrarEjercicio(){
let laTemperatura = Number(document.querySelector("#val1").value);

let temperaturaEnFahrenheit = convertirCelsiusAFahrenheit(laTemperatura);
let mensaje;
if (temperaturaEnFahrenheit) {
    mensaje = "la temperatura en fahrenheit es "+ temperaturaEnFahrenheit;
    
}

document.querySelector("#resultado").innerHTML = mensaje;


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="Ejercicio.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <label for="val1">Ingrese temperatura:</label>
        <input type="number" id="val1"><br>
        <input type="button" value="Convertir" id="btn">
    </form>
    <p id="resultado"></p>
    
</body>
</html>
```